# How to use a few dispatch in nuxt fetch?

Tags: promise, fetch, nuxt.js

I create a site in nuxt and got data from worpdress api.
I have a few store: home.js, solutions.js, tipo.js, portfolio.js and options.js.

In fetch i check, if the store array is empty, than call dispatch and fill arrays.

```js
export default {
  async fetch({ store }) {
    try {
      if (store.getters['home/home'].length === 0) {
        await store.dispatch('home/fetchHome');
      }
      if (store.getters["solutions/getSolutions"].length === 0) {
        await store.dispatch('solutions/fetchSolutions');
      }
      if (store.getters["tipo/getTipo"].length === 0) {
        await store.dispatch('tipo/fetchTipo');
      }
      if (store.getters["portfolio/getPortfolio"].length === 0) {
        await store.dispatch('portfolio/fetchPortfolio');
      }
      if(store.getters["options/getOptions"].length === 0){
        await store.dispatch('options/fetchOptions');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, 'e no data')
    }
  },
  components: { HomeContacts, PortofolioSlider, Clients, ChiSiamo, Solutions, HomeIntro }
}
```

But the problem is, that the page is loading to long time. Because i call dispatches throw await, and i think, this is the problem.

How can i call all dispatches in fethc, without async, but parallel?

I see the advantage of working with fetch over asyncData in that only the first time when I load the page, I need to wait a little, the arrays will fill up and when I get to the current page from another page, there will be no requests through the api, and the data will be output from the store.

It's just that there is very little information on nuxt in terms of ideology, how to work and what is better to use and when. In next, this is better.

This method doesn't work.

```js
fetch({ store }) {
  const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (store.getters['home/home'].length === 0) {
      resolve(store.dispatch('home/fetchHome'));
    }
  });
  const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (store.getters["solutions/getSolutions"].length === 0) {
      resolve(store.dispatch('solutions/fetchSolutions'));
    }
  });
  const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (store.getters["tipo/getTipo"].length === 0) {
      resolve(store.dispatch('tipo/fetchTipo'));
    }
  });
  const promise4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (store.getters["portfolio/getPortfolio"].length === 0) {
      resolve(store.dispatch('portfolio/fetchPortfolio'));
    }
  });
  const promise5 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (store.getters["options/getOptions"].length === 0) {
      resolve(store.dispatch('options/fetchOptions'));
    }
  });
  Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4, promise5])
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: What's the approach on Next on this?

Comment: page is loading to long time = wordpress api, the solution is to make your own wp api with reduced features (bog-standard api will load all of wp, but simply not output html) or make less calls or as needed, additionally you could use a loop to save a few lines and not make it async

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so nothing related to front-end really. What are the differences between Nuxt and Next for data fetching, front-end-wise only?

Comment: async still plays a factor

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `async` is the same in Next and Nuxt so far.

Comment: @kissu yes async is part of js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- `store.dispatch()` returns Promise,
- the first attempt in the question is generally correct,
- the objective is to perform relevant dispatches in parallel,

then:

- elimitate `await` from the `store.dispatch()` sequence,
- accumulate the promises returned by `store.dispatch()` in an array,
- don't use a `new Promise()` wrapper,
- `await` the Promise returned by `Promise.all(promises)`.

  ```js
  export default {
      async fetch({ store }) {
          try {
              let promises = [];
              if (store.getters['home/home'].length === 0) {
                  promises.push(store.dispatch('home/fetchHome'));
              }
              if (store.getters['solutions/getSolutions'].length === 0) {
                  promises.push(store.dispatch('solutions/fetchSolutions'));
              }
              if (store.getters['tipo/getTipo'].length === 0) {
                  promises.push(store.dispatch('tipo/fetchTipo'));
              }
              if (store.getters['portfolio/getPortfolio'].length === 0) {
                  promises.push(store.dispatch('portfolio/fetchPortfolio'));
              }
              if(store.getters['options/getOptions'].length === 0) {
                  promises.push(store.dispatch('options/fetchOptions'));
              }
              let data = await Promise.all(promises);
              console.log(data);
          } catch (e) {
              console.log(e);
          }
      },
      components: { HomeContacts, PortofolioSlider, Clients, ChiSiamo, Solutions, HomeIntro }
  }
  ```

For convenience, this can be proceduralised as follows:

```
export default {
    async fetch({ store }) {
        try {
            let paths = [
                { get: 'home/home',              fetch: 'home/fetchHome' },
                { get: 'solutions/getSolutions', fetch: 'solutions/fetchSolutions' },
                { get: 'tipo/getTipo',           fetch: 'tipo/fetchTipo' },
                { get: 'portfolio/getPortfolio', fetch: 'portfolio/fetchPortfolio' },
                { get: 'options/getOptions',     fetch: 'options/fetchOptions' }
            ];
            let promises = paths.filter(p => store.getters[p.get].length === 0).map(p => store.dispatch(p.fetch));
            let data = await Promise.all(promises);
            console.log(data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
    components: { HomeContacts, PortofolioSlider, Clients, ChiSiamo, Solutions, HomeIntro }
}
```

It may make more sense to define the `paths` array elsewhere in the code and pass it to a simplified `fetch()`, giving it the profile :

```
    fetch({ store, paths })
```

If it still doesn't work, then there's something your're not telling us.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I resolved this question in the same way. 

https://i.imgur.com/MfS3O3M.png


Please, can you help me with the same kind of fetch, but with commits.

https://i.imgur.com/ciBWy0A.png


Thanks a lot.

Comment: @serii, I may be able to help with commits but you will have to ask formally by posting another question.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` can be useful here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
Or even `Promise.allSettled()`, depending on what you're trying to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Then, this is a matter of displaying something while your page does the fetching. You could use a `v-if="$fetchState.pending"` at the top level of your page to display a loader while the whole thing is being fetched.

There is nothing related to ideology here, there are 2 hooks that do data fetching by either blocking the render of the page (`asyncData()`) or allowing you to render it while the data is fetched (`fetch()`).

Nothing related to the framework by itself, you're free to do as you'd like.

Comment: For my opinion, the problem is, that i use to much await. 
Because the first await should be executed, then the second, the third.
And how to make requests to the server parallel, as we say in gulp, parallel and series.

Comment: If i will add promise like this, this will solve the problem? 

`
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  resolve(
      if (store.getters['home/home'].length === 0) {
        store.dispatch('home/fetchHome');
      }

);
 }, 2000);
});
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  resolve('Promise2 выполнен');
 }, 1500);
});
Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  .then((data) => console.log(data[0], data[1]))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
`

Comment: @serii The 2 first line of my answer are related to your initial question of having several API calls at the same time. You should not use `setTimeout` here because this is not something reliable, `async/await` does a far better job here.